# As of January 2020, what is the single longest duration firing executed with a Raptor engine?

Tags: engines, engine-design, raptor

Can someone cut through the woo for me?

As of January 2020, what is the single longest duration firing executed with a Raptor engine? Have any successfully run for full mission duration?

Sourced answers only, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The longest test firing of a developmental Raptor engine was 100 seconds, according to [Elon's talk at IAC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdUX3ypDVwI) on September 29, 2017. The duration was limited by tanks, and would only have been superseded by one of the flight burns, which @Machavity has given a [good summary](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41083/12102), the longest of which was under 60 seconds.

Comment: Interesting, sounds like their test stand can't support a full duration test firing.

Answer (score 3):

On [July 25, 2019 Starship Mark 1 mock-up test flight](https://spaceflightnow.com/2019/07/26/spacexs-starship-prototype-aces-first-untethered-hop-test/) ran for 22 seconds

> The silver test vehicle, made of stainless steel, took off around 10:45 p.m. CDT Thursday (11:45 p.m. EDT; 0345 GMT) at SpaceX’s launch and test facility in Boca Chica, Texas, a beachside community near Brownsville.
>
> The Starship prototype, known as the Starship Hopper or “Starhopper,” was supposed to fly to a height of about 65 feet (20 meters), move sideways a bit, and then settle back on the ground on its three-legged landing gear.
>
> Elon Musk, SpaceX’s founder and CEO, declared **the 22-second test flight** a success.

On [Aug 27, 2019 Starhopper flew again](https://spaceflightnow.com/2019/08/27/spacex-launches-starship-hopper-on-dramatic-test-flight/). There was no official time given, but the video puts it around 57-60 seconds (can't see when the engine shut down)

"Starhopper" had a single Raptor engine. [This craft was destroyed in a November mishap](https://twitter.com/NASASpaceflight/status/1197265917589303296) (the mishap was not involving the Raptor engine itself) so no other flights have been made.